# Hibernate ConstraintViolationException: could not delete the SortedSet Collection of Child

Tags: java, hibernate, treeset

I have the following two classes: `Claim` (parent) and `ClaimInsurance` (child). They are as follows:

```
public class Claim {    
  private SortedSet<ClaimInsurance> claimInsurances = new TreeSet<ClaimInsurance>();

  @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy="claim", orphanRemoval=true)
  @Sort(type=SortType.NATURAL)
  public SortedSet<ClaimInsurance> getClaimInsurances() {
    return this.claimInsurances;
  }

  public void setClaimInsurances(SortedSet<ClaimInsurance> claimInsurances) {
    this.claimInsurances = claimInsurances;
  }
}
```

And:

```
public class ClaimInsurance implements java.io.Serializable, Comparable<ClaimInsurance> {
  private Claim claim;

  @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
  @JoinColumn(name="ClaimId", nullable=false)
  public Claim getClaim() {
    return this.claim;
  }

  public void setClaim(Claim claim) {
    this.claim = claim;
  }
}
```

When I try to delete the `Claim` it gives following Exception

```
org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not delete: [com.omnimd.pms.beans.Claim#201]
...
Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint "FK_RCMSClaimInsuranceTable_RCMSClaimTable". The conflict occurred in database "Omnimdv12", table "dbo.RCMSClaimInsuranceTable", column 'ClaimId'.
```

When I change the `claimInsurances` mapping in the `Claim` class as follows, everything works fine:

```
private Set<ClaimInsurance> claimInsurances = new HashSet<ClaimInsurance>();

@OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy="claim", orphanRemoval=true)
public Set<ClaimInsurance> getClaimInsurances() {
  return this.claimInsurances;
}

public void setClaimInsurances(Set<ClaimInsurance> claimInsurances) {
  this.claimInsurances = claimInsurances;
}
```

It seems that the problem is when I use `Set` (`HashSet`) in the mapping it works, but if I instead use `SortedSet` (`TreeSet`) it gives an error.

What could be the actual problem? What am I missing?

Comment: How is your `compareTo()` method implemented?

Comment: `public int compareTo(ClaimInsurance other) {
  return this.getInsuranceOrderCodeMaster().compareTo(other.getInsuranceOrderCodeMaster());`  and here is the InsuranceOrderCodeMaster's compareTo()........`public int compareTo(InsuranceOrderCodeMaster other) {
  
  Integer this_id  = Integer.valueOf(this.getInsuranceOrderCodeId());
  Integer other_id = Integer.valueOf(other.getInsuranceOrderCodeId());
  
  return this_id.compareTo(other_id);
 }
 }`

Comment: And can you have several ClaimInsurances with the same insurance code master for the same Claim?

Comment: No. there is unique insurance code for each `ClaimInsurance` of the same `Claim`

Comment: Shot in the dark, but are the equals() and hashCode() methods consistent with compareTo()? Have you turned on SQL logging to find which rows Hibernate tries to delete and in which order?

Comment: In SQL log i found that `ClaimInsurance` is getting deleted first and then `Claim`. `equals()` and `hashCode()` are NOT consistent with `compareTo()`, could that be a problem ? because `equals()` and `hashCode()` are based on my Primary_Key field while `compareTo()` is based on another field which is InsuranceOrderCode

Comment: I've never used a sorted set with Hibernate, and don't know the exact rules. But I wouldn't be surprised if it needed compareTo and equals to be consistent.

Comment: ok..my mistake..you asked if I can have several `ClaimInsurances` with the same insurance code master for the same `Claim`? I said no, but i was wrong...actually there was such duplicate `InsuranceOrderCodeMaster' and it was creating the problem. Its solved now...thank you for your help...:)

Comment: You should explain what the problem was and how you solved it in an answer to your own question, for the posterity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. The problem is resolved now. with the help of @JB Nizet

For same `Claim` i was having several `ClaimInsurance` whose `compareTo()` giving same result.

I changed the `compareTo()` in `ClaimInsurance` such that it will return different values for same `Claim`..that's it, its working now.